# Android Studio META-INF malformed error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error when uploading the APK to Google Play Store even though the signed APK is generated successfully in Android Studio 3.1.3

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_MISSING_ZIP_ENTRY_REFERENCED_IN_MANIFEST: assets/www/images/appicon/Icon entry referenced by META-INF/MANIFEST.MF not found in the APK ERROR: JAR_SIG_UNNNAMED_MANIFEST_SECTION: Malformed META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: invidual section #47 does not have a name

Can anyone tell me where I can locate this or how to fix this error?

Many thanks

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="127" android:versionName="0.1.997" package="fyt.cordova.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="flavoryt" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="fyt.cordova.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="fyt.cordova.app.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="fyt.cordova.app.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Your error suggest correctly and clearly that Your manifest is referencing some file which You have deleted but entry in manifest is still persist.

> JAR_SIG_MISSING_ZIP_ENTRY_REFERENCED_IN_MANIFEST
>
> JAR manifest references an entry which is not there in the APK.

Follwoing seems to be an icon file whose reference still exist in Your manifest.

> assets/www/images/appicon/Icon

You can use tools like [ApkVerifier](https://github.com/abutun/apk-verifier) to test before You upload on Play Store.
Additionally [here](https://jakewharton.github.io/tools-apksig/com/android/apksig/ApkVerifier.Issue.html) is a list of all such errors

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I have just edited the original post with the actual manifest file. I am unable to find the assets/www/images/appicon/Icon section?

Comment: Did you change this path in your current release android:icon="@mipmap/icon"

Comment: Nope that was never changed, it was left as standard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what the problem was.

It was a link to an icon file **outside** of the android folder itself that the grunt process failed to pull from. I added the file in manually and it worked out.

Thanks for all your input.